# How do I update the path variable in windows terminal without closing and reopening?

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

I just installed something through `chocolatey` and unable to access it through my currently open Windows Terminal. On Linux, I could do a `source ~/.bashrc` or something to update my `$path` I changed in `.bashrc`.
Also, opening a new tab in the same terminal doesn't update the path either. I have to close the whole Windows Terminal window (hence closing all the tabs) and reopen the Windows Terminal.
Is there a way to have the current window load the latest path (so it can be available in a new tab)? Or better yet, to update the path in the current terminal?